# Why cant you have multiple links on the same extern block?

Tags: rust, ffi

I have multiple C libraries that I want to link to my Rust project. To do this I use multiple link attributes on the same extern block.

```
use libc::{c_int};

#[link(name = "zlib", kind = "static")]
#[link(name = "libpng", kind = "static")]
#[link(name = "vec", kind = "static")] 
extern "C" {        
    pub fn entrypoint(argc: c_int, argv: *mut *mut u8) -> c_int;
    pub fn just_crash() -> c_int;
}
```

I then use a `build.rs` script to add a search path on the directory containing my C libraries (.a files).

```
fn main() {
    stop_if_unknown_os();
    let dir = env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();
    let cwd = Path::new(&dir);

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", cwd.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}/../install/lib", cwd.display());
}
```

When I go to run `cargo build -vv`, I get some errors indicating that the definition of libpng functions used in the vec library, could not be found.

When I place the link attributes on multiple extern blocks it compiles successfully.

```
#[link(name = "vec", kind = "static")] 
extern "C" {        
    pub fn entrypoint(argc: c_int, argv: *mut *mut u8) -> c_int;
    pub fn just_crash() -> c_int;
}

#[link(name = "png16", kind = "static")]
extern "C" {}

#[link(name = "zlib", kind = "static")]
extern "C" {}
```

My question is why did the previous option not work?

Comment: Note that the order in which they appear matters. if vec contains png functions, linking to png must happen _AFTER_ vec. In your second example, the order is different.

Comment: Does they all have the same interface?

Comment: I have tested @somnium 's idea and he is correct.

Comment: @AlexN No, each library has a different public interface in their included headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somnium was correct, in mentioning that the order the link attributes are defined in, can fix this problem.